# Does event object get overriden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a jQuery animation that calls itself recursively. To make its timing dynamic I pass additional arguments when I use `trigger`. The code is:

```
var $forward = function(event, settings) {
    $(this).stop();
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this).prop('scrollHeight') / 2) {
        $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() - $(this).prop('scrollHeight') / 2);
    }

    $scroll_step = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') / 2 - $(this).scrollTop();

    $(this).animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).prop('scrollHeight') / 2
    }, (1 / (!!settings ? settings.speed : $settings.speed)) * $scroll_step * 1000, "linear", function() { $forward(event, settings) });

};
```

In the bottom right you can see `function() { $forward(event, settings) }` as the callback. I wanted to preserve the value of setting in secind, third and so on recursions. I use dynamic speed with trigger as:

```
$(".marquee").on("forward", $forward);
$(".marquee").eq(0).trigger("forward", {speed: 50});
```

It seems to work well. My question is does `event` in callback get overridden by the `event` parameter of first line `var $forward = function(event, settings)`?

Should I change callback code to: `function() { $forward(event2, settings) }`

Comment: Since you are not using `event` anywhere in your function, I wonder why you would care?

Comment: @Bergi, it's needed because speed is passed in trigger. If I remove event then settings parameter is supposed to be event. Also in my actual plugin now I see problems in Firefox. There seems to be infinite recursion. I am on phone now so could update tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, of course you need to declare a parameter, but you don't need to use it anywhere. Just `function $forward(_, settings) { …` and `$forward(null, settings)`.

Comment: @Bergi I thought `settings` acts as a property of `event` like `event.settings` and in each new occurrence of `var any = 1; $forward(any, settings)`, `any` becomes `1` not the event object.